# SQL query help in Yii2

Tags: yii2

I have a three tables to join. (users, user_module, module). from users table i want to get Fname field. from user_module table i want to get assign module number for the student. from module table i want to get module field.(name of the module).

**users table**
   id     Fname 
    1      Asela

**user_module table**
   studentID   moduleID 
             1                 1

**module table**
   id       module 
1        AST

my code to get result from the tables

```
 $assignModule = new SqlDataProvider([
                                        'sql'=> "SELECT Fname AS Student_name, A3.moduleID As Module_no, A2.module As Module_name FROM users A1"
                                                ."LEFT JOIN user_module A3 ON A3.studentID = A1.id"
                                                ."LEFT JOIN module A2 ON A3.moduleID = A2.id "
                                                . "WHERE A2.id IN (SELECT studentID FROM user_module)",
```

**error** 
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'A1.idLEFT' in 'on clause'

Comment: Use  `SELECT id, Fname, module FROM users, module...........`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this query

```
$sql =    "SELECT A1.Fname As Student_name,
                                A3.moduleID As Module_no,
                                A2.module As Module_name,

                                FROM 
                                users A1

                                LEFT OUTER JOIN user_module A3 ON A1.id=A3.studentID
                                LEFT OUTER JOIN module A2 ON A3.moduleID=A2.id

                                WHERE id IN (SELECT studentID FROM user_module)";
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend doing as Bloodhound said and change how you're doing your quotes. The way you are concatenating your query string is causing the text to bump together, likely breaking the query. For example in your query:

```
"SELECT Fname AS Student_name, A3.moduleID As Module_no, A2.module As Module_name FROM users A1"
                                            ."LEFT JOIN user_module A3 ON A3.studentID = A1.id"
                                            ."LEFT JOIN module A2 ON A3.moduleID = A2.id "
                                            . "WHERE A2.id IN (SELECT studentID FROM user_module)",
```

It's being read as:

```
SELECT Fname AS Student_name, A3.moduleID As Module_no, A2.module As Module_name FROM users A1LEFT JOIN user_module A3 ON A3.studentID = A1.idLEFT JOIN module A2 ON A3.moduleID = A2.id WHERE A2.id IN (SELECT studentID FROM user_module)
```